# Flip the OR condition return wrong access in firebase realtime rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am learning Firebase rules for security but I see something strange when I flip the OR condition it returns true as excepted but it returns wrong otherwise

this is the JSON tree

```
{
  "-LnOK0641vZRqJ1k5tCc" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "ndndnjelwjdjrkeldnhfkelenjrkkee\n",
    "id" : 4,
    "instruction" : "nfhrjejwkldjfjejejhdhejejejejje",
    "title" : "title11",
    "username" : "bdjsjd"
  },
  "-LnOby-AZv2D-FkgBopU" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "bdnwjksbxksndjejwldjjdjekwldnd",
    "id" : 5,
    "instruction" : "hejelwldhfhekekdhdjejekdk",
    "title" : "bsndnfhdkwmsbdjs",
    "username" : "bdjsjd"
  },
  "-LnOc2Y5DT5XvwJv6NJu" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "ndnskajdhfiwldhdoelw",
    "id" : 6,
    "instruction" : "jsksksklfhfjejeksjfjiei",
    "title" : "5ndnsjsndbdkwlaldhjd",
    "username" : "bdjsjd"
  }  
}
```

Firebase rule when it is return data

```
"$uid" : {
".read" : true,
".write" : "((!data.exists() && auth != null) || (auth.uid == root.child('Users').child(data.child('username').val()).child('uid').val()))"
      }
```

Firebase reject returning

```
"$uid" : {
 ".read" : true,
 ".write" : "((auth.uid == root.child('Users').child(data.child('username').val()).child('uid').val()) || (!data.exists() && auth != null) )"

      }
```

I flip OR only and not the same result

EDIT 
when I use Admin permission the rejected one will return allowed access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is an error evaluating a condition in your security rules, the entire rule immediately fails.

In your first ruleset, you correctly guard against errors, so the rules engine evaluates:

```
!data.exists() && auth != null) ||
```

And if there is no data, and no authenticated user, it allows the operation (since you have an `||`).

In your second ruleset, your condition starts with:

```
auth.uid == ...
```

If there is no authenticated user, `auth` is non-existing or `null` and `auth.uid` throws an error, resulting in a rejection of the operation.

Comment: thanks ... you mean if the auth is null and I use it with `auth.uid` it will throw like NPE and directly reject without return to the next `||`code?